# Displaying GeoServer vector tile using OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, vector-tiles

I'm using OpenLayers 5.3 and GeoServer to create a web map. Previously, I was using Leaflet and was able to display my layer as a vector tile. Now, I'm having issues getting the vector tile to display on my base map. I suspect a projection issue, but I don't see where I'm going wrong.

The data is in EPSG:3297. However, using leaflet I didn't need to transform it--is this different for OpenLayers?

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html -->
<html>
<head>
<title>SIG webviewer</title>
<script src="ol.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ol.css">


<style>
/*Set the dimensions of our map */
.map {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<!--Create our map object -->
<div id="map" class="map"></div>

<script>
var style_simple = new ol.style.Style({
  fill: new ol.style.Fill({
    color: '#ADD8E6'
  }),
  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: '#880000',
    width: 1
  })
});

  function simpleStyle(feature) {
    return style_simple;
  }

// Set the coordinate system
var projection_epsg_no = '900913';
// Set the variable for storing the workspace:layername
var s_coupureaerien_layer = 'test:elec_appareil_coupure_aerien_hta';
// Creating the full vectorTile url
var s_coupureaerienUrl = '/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/' + s_coupureaerien_layer + '@EPSG%3A' + projection_epsg_no + '@pbf/{z}/{x}/{-y}.pbf';
// Creating the Leaflet vectorGrid object
//var s_coupureaerien_vectorgrid = L.vectorGrid.protobuf(s_coupureaerienUrl, vectorTileOptions);
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-149.3, -17.7]),
    zoom: 7
  }),
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.VectorTile({
      style:simpleStyle,
      source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
        //tilePixelRatio: 1, // oversampling when > 1
        //tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({maxZoom: 19}),
        format: new ol.format.MVT(),
        //defaultDataProjection: 'EPSG: 900913',
        url: s_coupureaerienUrl,
      }),

    }),
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM({
        url: "https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
      })
    })]
});

map.on('click', function(e) {
  console.log(map.getLayers());
})

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have some things commented out that I was testing/considering the culprit of my problems, but no luck.

Comment: If you got it working in Leaflet, then the easiest way of debugging would be to compare network requests for vector layers tiles in Leaflet and in OpenLayers.

Answer (score 0):

if you're working with localhost (and listening on port 8080) you should:

s_coupureaerienUrl = 'http://localhost:8080' + s_coupureaerienUrl